# How to extract a file name from an URI in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, url, uri

I have an URL like this -

> `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sathyatest12-blog.appspot.com/o/85fa93fa-1ca7-4055-b6b3-6a41db4s498b-testcup1.png?alt=media&token=4dfd3ca0-a55b-4052-956c-94a2bs13c77e`

of which I need to get the file name. In this case,

> 85fd93fa-1ca7-4055-b6d3-6a41db4s498b-testcup1.png

I tried using regex as suggested in other answers but I am unable to write complicated expressions.

I tried using [JavaScripts Good parts by Coderholic](http://www.coderholic.com/javascript-the-good-parts/) but it is not giving me what I want. I found a generic regex from there which I am pasting below

```js
var parse_url = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;
var url = 'http://www.ora.com:80/goodparts?q#fragment';

var result = parse_url.exec(url);
var names = ['url', 'scheme', 'slash', 'host', 'port', 'path', 'query', 'hash'];
var blanks = '       ';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < names.length; i += 1) {
    document.writeln(names[i] + ':' + blanks.substring(names[i].length), result[i]);
}
```

But the above code snippet is giving me an output like this.

> /v0/b/sathyatest12-blog.appspot.com/o/85fa93fa-1ca7-4055-b6b3-6a41db4s498b-testcup1.png

Please guide me on how to achieve the following result

> 85fa93fa-1ca7-4055-b6b3-6a41db4s498b-testcup1.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem simply like below

```
var url_string = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sathyatest12-blog.appspot.com/o/85fa93fa-1ca7-4055-b6b3-6a41db4s498b-testcup1.png?alt=media&token=4dfd3ca0-a55b-4052-956c-94a2bs13c77e"; //window.location.href
firstPos = url_string.lastIndexOf('/');
lastPos = url_string.indexOf('?');
var result = url_string.slice(firstPos+1, lastPos);

console.log(result);
```

I have tested this on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use the [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)  ?

```js
var URL_val = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sathyatest12-blog.appspot.com/o/85fa93fa-1ca7-4055-b6b3-6a41db4s498b-testcup1.png?alt=media&token=4dfd3ca0-a55b-4052-956c-94a2bs13c77e'
  , URL_Obj = new URL(URL_val)
  ;
let lastOne = URL_Obj.pathname.split('/').pop()
  
console.log(`lastOne: ${lastOne}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve the same result first to reverse the string since we cannot find the last index of `/` using regex. But we can find the first index of `?` if we can reverse the string.

```js
const str =
  "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/sathyatest12-blog.appspot.com/o/85fa93fa-1ca7-4055-b6b3-6a41db4s498b-testcup1.png?alt=media&token=4dfd3ca0-a55b-4052-956c-94a2bs13c77e";

const reverse = str.split("").reverse().join("");
const regex = /(?<=\?)(.*?)\//;
const match = reverse.match(regex);
if (match) {
  const result = match[1].split("").reverse().join("");
  console.log(result);
}
```